# RichTechBox and justify alignment

Tags: winforms

Is any way to justify text in Windows Forms RichTextBox control?

Answer (score 2):

justification is not supported per se. look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200717100111/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/182.aspx) for a tutorial on how to extend the richtextbox to support justification.